# Is an empty item a problem in LaTeX eqnarray?

Tags: equations, arrays

The following LaTeX code looks pretty straightforward to me:

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
& \lambda_l \mathbf{l}\cdot\mathbf{r} & = & \lambda_r \mathbf{l}\cdot\mathbf{r} \nonumber \\
\therefore & \mathbf{l}\cdot\mathbf{r} & = & 0 \nonumber
\end{eqnarray*}
```

but it results in the error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.78 ..._l \mathbf{l}\cdot\mathbf{r} & = & \lambda
                                                  _r \mathbf{l}\cdot\mathbf{...
```

If I remove enough ampersands, I get a clean execution, but then I lose the alignment I am trying to get.

Is there a problem with the implicit first empty item on the first line, or is it caused by something else?

Comment: There can be at most two `&` per line. On the other hand, `eqnarray` is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: @egreg  Well, that clears things up.  I am looking at my LaTeX manual right now where eqnarray is discussed and I notice for the first time that all the examples have only two ampersands.  But I can't see anywhere where it is explicitly stated that this is the limit.  Could you tell me where this is documented?  Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be using `eqnarray` to begin with: it's broken; see [`eqnarray` vs `align`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196)

Comment: @egreg -- as much as i don't like `eqnarray`, i never thought of it as "broken" to the extent that it would produce such a misleading error message.  now i agree -- it's *definitely* broken!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `eqnarray` environment allows at most two `&` per row.

On the other hand it is broken and should not be used, see [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196)

Here are two realizations with `amsmath` environments. My favorite is the latter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&            &\quad \lambda_l \mathbf{l}\cdot\mathbf{r}  & = \lambda_r \mathbf{l}\cdot\mathbf{r}\\
& \therefore &\quad \mathbf{l}\cdot\mathbf{r}            & = 0
\end{alignat*}
\lipsum*[4]
\begin{align*}
\lambda_l \mathbf{l}\cdot\mathbf{r}  & = \lambda_r \mathbf{l}\cdot\mathbf{r}\\
\shortintertext{therefore}
\mathbf{l}\cdot\mathbf{r}            & = 0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]